# State management library choice and implementation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-context

Im trying to use state management to modify my app and make it more generic. basicaly my app is react web app embedded with tableau dashboards, i need that specific routes (which hold specific dashboards) will be populated in the app through reading a json from the backend which specifies the project we want.

i need it in two ways:

1. UI project switch which lets me switch between projects
2. through the JWT which the front side recieves from a login attempt (upon sucsess)

i figured the only state needs managing is the navigation bar and its data, ill render the relevant paths and thus enable only the relevant dashboards by project/user.

this is the code for my navbar:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavbarData } from "./NavbarData";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import "./Navbar.css";
import Hamburger from "./Icons/Hamburger.svg";
import "./Icons/p_logo_color.png";
import Persona from "./Icons/Persona.svg";
import Logout from "./Icons/Logout.svg";
//someting





//Navbar function
function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  const [pageName, setPageName] = useState('Operational Overview');
  const location = useLocation();
  

  

  const getPageTitleByUrl = (path) => {
    NavbarData.filter((navItem) => {
    
      if(navItem.path === path) {
        setPageName(navItem.title);
      }
     return true; 
    } )
    


  };

  const userConfigPageTitle = (path) => {
    setPageName("User Information");

  }

  

  useEffect(() => {
    if(location.pathname) {
      getPageTitleByUrl(location.pathname);
    }
  }, [location] ); 
  

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
             <img src={Hamburger} alt="hamburger" onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>

          <div className="criminal-records">Elecciones Guatemala |</div> 
          <div className="pageTitle"><h1>{pageName}</h1></div>

          <>
          <div><img className="userIcon" src={Persona} alt="persona" /> </div>
          <div className="userButton">User123#</div>
          </>

          <Link to='/' className="logout-button">
          <div><img className="logoutIcon" src={Logout} alt="persona" /> </div>
          <div className="logoutButton">Logout</div> 
          </Link>
          
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className="navbar-toggle">
          
            </li>
            {NavbarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
        
                  <span className="navbutton-icon">{item.icon}</span><span className="navbutton-text" >{item.title}</span>
                    
                    
                  </Link>
                  
                </li>
                
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

and this is NavbarData:

```
import React from 'react'



import startpageIcon from './Icons/startpage.svg';
import performance from './Icons/performance.svg';
import bars from './Icons/bars.svg';
import simulation from './Icons/simulation.svg';
import fraud from './Icons/fraud.svg';
import deployForNow from './Icons/Profiles.svg';
import Planning from './Icons/plan.svg';
import deployment from './Icons/layer1.svg';
import barswithperson from './Icons/barswithperson.svg'





export const NavbarData = [
    {
        title: 'Simulación',
        path: '/monitoringoverview',
        icon: <img  src={simulation} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Empadronados",
        path: "/performancequality",
        icon: <img src={barswithperson} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    }


]
```

so basically all i need is to connect the dropdown switcher to change the json structured data inside NavbarData, and define each of these variations as state.
So since this is quite a simple state managing task i want to use React Context to solve it, how can i do it?

Thanks in advance!